# Rebase all the branches (both children and grandchilden) from their ancestor

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a Git repository as follows:

```
A-B-F  (master)
|\   
C \    (feature-1)
   D   (feature-2)
    \
     E (feature-3)
```

Is there any way to rebase automatically all the feature branches (both children and grandchild) to F as follows?

```
A-B-F (master)
    |\   
    C'\    (feature-1)
       D'  (feature-2)
        \
         E'(feature-3)
```

I have checked the replies of [Rebasing a branch including all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children) and [How to rebase a series of branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860484/how-to-rebase-a-series-of-branches), but neither they are covering this particular case, nor a definitive answer is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anwser is the same as in the related questions: there is nothing built-in in git for this. You can do this manually as described below. After that you can try to put it in a script...

This is how you do it manually:

```
git checkout feature-1
git rebase master
git checkout feature-2
git rebase master
git checkout feature-3
git rebase feature-2
```

to help you on the way starting to script this your self:

```
git branch --contains <sha-1> | xargs -n 1 | grep -v "\*" | grep -v master
```

will give you a list of all branches that contain commit `<sha-1>`. Then you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208948/display-all-first-level-descendant-branches-using-git) to find code on how to find first-level descendants... Putting these two informations together; you'll be able to scripts what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am currently doing. I have specifically asked for an automated way...

Comment: as I told you, there is nothing in git that will allow that; you need to define clearly what you want to automate and how... what branches will need to be rebased; and on which branch...? You'll have to write that yourself; but I can help you on the way if necessary

Comment: ok, how about a more automatic way, such as find all the children of a specific commit (A) and rebase them to another specific commit (F). If there are grandchildren, rebase them to their new parents etc.

Comment: @joko if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.